# React Native - OneSignal Push Notifications concept setup with conditioning

Tags: javascript, php, react-native, push-notification, onesignal

I have created a school app which shows the students about the class if it is going to take place or not (Like substitute plan).

In the app, students have two options in the settings, first to select the class (I send the selected class as a tag in OneSignal) and then to select the courses they have in that class (The courses are stored in app local storage in an array).

Now I use these settings that the student has set (the class and the courses) to pass it as a parameter in my API to get the filtered results, and it is also working good.

The problem is just now how should I notify the students when there is a new result or an update?

I did notifications setup only for classes and it is working, first I compare the results and if there is any new result in the new and previous state, the students selected that class will be notified.

But now I also want to apply the course's condition, that if the student has selected any courses then my server side (server side is in PHP) should first check for an update of the selected class and then only send the students the notification which has selected that course, and if the student has selected many courses and there are more than one update for the selected courses only one notification should be sent.

Many Thanks in Advance! I hope I was able to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i understand u want to select a subset of students dynamically. can we register all students for notif and then call the onesignal api on a subset on the fly?

Comment: Yes we can, but how will onsignal know that what courses the student has selected?

Comment: onesignal doesnt send notif without your trigger. when u trigger, just provide a deviceid array that you construct out of your student/course criteria